# Embed on-premise SharePoint page in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

A customer has an on-premise farm with url http://xx-robot-xx:5601
Is it possible in anyway to embed this into SharePoint online? In settings you can do something like this:

[image]

But this do not allow any ports and does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to use the SharePoint online embed web part if does not work follow the below approach.

Create alternate access mapping for the said port URL, then update the host configuration in the web front end server then configure the newly alternate access mapping URL in the HTML security setting.

You may refer the below thread as well:

[Display SharePoint Online in an iframe on different domain](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140253/display-sharepoint-online-in-an-iframe-on-different-domain)

For embed web part in SharePoint Online refer the below MSDN article:

[Add content to your page using the Embed web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8)

Comment: Is the alertnate url to get rid of the port?

Comment: Yes, you are right. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciated.