# Display Front End of SharePoint in other portal

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, 2016

Please give me an idea about this:
We have SharePoint server 2016 and we want to show the front-end of SharePoint 2016 in our portal.

If a user can click on a file then the file is open or uploaded to our portal.

Answer (score 0):

You can display SharePoint pages on an external site through an **iframe**.

By default, SharePoint prevents cross-domain IFRAMING of pages as a security measure to prevent clickjacking. But developers can opt-out of clickjacking (*not recommended. do it in your own risk*) protection by adding the **AllowFraming** control to their .aspx pages.
*<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />*

You will need to **modify the master-page** (*be sure to keep a backup/copy*) and add the following tags, which allows the page content to be presented inside an Iframe element.

Location 1:
Search the master page for PlaceHolderPageTitle as your location indicator and place the tag under it.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
<!– custom tag –>
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />
```

Location 2:
Search the master page for WebPartAdder as your location indicator and place the tag under it.

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartAdder ID="WebPartAdder" runat="server" />
<!– custom tag –>
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />
```

After these steps, you can display the SharePoint page in external sites using

```
<iframe src="{{sharepoint url here}}"></iframe>
```

References:

http://sharepointsharks.blog/how-to-resolve-content-cannot-be-displayed-in-a-frame-on-a-master-page/

[Display SharePoint Online in an iframe on different domain](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140253/display-sharepoint-online-in-an-iframe-on-different-domain)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sites/cannot-display-sharepoint-pages-in-iframe